# angular 4 template driven form - mark from one field secondone as touched

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

i have two fields 
f.e.

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(f.value, f.valid)">
<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" #name="ngModel" required minlength="5">
    <label>Street</label>
    <input type="text" name="street" [(ngModel)]="user.surname" #surname="ngModel" required>
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

i want to mark one of those fields from secondone as touched, it is possible?
i tried to use (ngModelChange)="surname.control.markAsTouched(true)" on name to mark surname as touched but it doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(ngModelChange)` will work when you change the first input value, you can use `(blur)` to mark the second touched when the first is.

```
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" #name="ngModel" 
  (ngModelChange)="surname.control.markAsTouched()" required minlength="5">
<input type="text" name="street" [(ngModel)]="user.surname" #surname="ngModel" required>
{{surname.touched | json}}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HDqe2nkf5IScXTAv2hfT?p=preview)